# Unable to read Korean character from device configuration (via SSH) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using netmiko to connect to Juniper firewall. I am able to connect and run a command without any problem. However the firewall configuration contains "Korean characters", it seems that the default netmiko encoding is unable to interpret it. Could you please advise if we can change the encoding value? or Do we use another ssh plugin instead of netmiko?

I did try to change the encoding option to euc-kr but got the same result.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
juniper = {
        'device_type': platform,
        'ip': hostip,
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'port' : 2222,
        'encoding' : 'euc-kr'
        }
    ssh_connect = ConnectHandler(**juniper)
    output1=ssh_connect.send_command('get config')

    print (output1)
```

The result on the screen is like this:

```
set address "VPN(Office)" "1.1.1.1(ȸǽ)" 
set group address "VPN(Office)" "OFFICE ▒▒ȭ▒▒뿪" add "xxx"
set group address "VPN(Office)" "OFFICE ▒▒ȭ▒▒뿪" add "yyy"
set group address "VPN(Office)" "OFFICE ▒▒ȭ▒▒뿪" add "zzz"
```

Comment: Can you please format your code examples and tell us what version of Python you are using?

Comment: This is probably a useless comment, but I've spent hours trying to debug problems like this only to find it was something simple: have you verified your terminal or display is configured to actually show the Korean characters in question? Debugging a coworker's script's problem displaying Japanese characters only to find hours later that he didn't actually have a Japanese font installed was frustration I'd rather not have anyone have to experience. And especially not the days of frustration he experienced before seeking help.

Comment: I am able to read the Korean character by using Putty. On my putty, I changed the "Character set translation" to "Use font encoding" [Putty option - Window >> Translation >> Remote character set:]. After then I am able to see Korean character via Putty.
I will try to check what you mentioned regarding the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: The Python version is 3.6. My computer has got Korean font. I am able to see Korean font on my cmd. Please see an example as follows;

C:\Python>ㅇㅇ
'ㅇㅇ'은(는) 내부 또는 외부 명령, 실행할 수 있는 프로그램, 또는
배치 파일이 아닙니다.

I am thinking when the script connects to the firewall and gets the configuration. It does not know how to interpret it. Please kindly advise.

Comment: Do anyone know how to change the encoding of Netmiko?